# Почему отступ у картинки справа в bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Всем привет, случился какой-то нонсенс, все было отлично, перезапустил проект, и вот у картинки `padding: 0 15px`, если поставить колонкам `padding: 0` то картинка вылазит на 15px за пределы экрана. Что за бред и в чем проблема?

```
        <div className='container-fluid bg-home-page'>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div>
                        <img src={bg_home}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.bg-home-page
    padding: 0
    max-width: 100%
    height: 100%
    .col-md-12
        padding: 0
        img 
            width: 100%
            max-height: 550px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.bg-home-page
    padding: 0
    max-width: 100%
    height: 100%
```

```html
      <div className='container-fluid bg-home-page'>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div>
                        <img class="img-fluid" src={bg_home}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Попробуй так. Я добавил класс на картинку + удалил css